# Scrapy (python) responses alternating between bytes and utf8

Tags: python, web, web-scraping, scrapy, http-headers

I am using scrapy web crawler, when scraping a site, the responses keep alternating between html and bytes, which are encoded utf8 but I receive and error when trying to decode them.

I have tried multiple different headers for encoding, accepting gzip, deflate, text/html;charset=utf-8, br but they keep giving me the same issue.

```
"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 11_0 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/604.1.38 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/11.0 Mobile/15A372 Safari/604.1",
"Accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3",
"Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.9",
"Accept-Encoding": "text/html;charset=utf-8",
```

To receive html instead of bytes, (here is a snippet of bytes received compared to html).
expected response

```
b'<!DOCTYPE html><html lang="en" xmlns:og="http://opengraphprotocol.org/schema/"><head><link rel="appl'
```

Actual response

```
b'\x93b\x92\x12)\x1d@I\xc1y\x00\x00h\xeb\x9d\x875\xaa\xd7\xc0\xfc\xb0q\x00\x00\xf0\x15\x0f\xdbF\xb1\xf3\x0f
```

Comment: it looks like compressed response. Don't use `"accepting gzip, br"`, keep only `"accepting deflate"`

Comment: you can also try to uncompress it - if server accepted `br` then `import brotli; print(brotli.decompress(b'\x93b\x92\x12...'))`

Comment: I would expect Scrapy to uncompress automatically. Have you disabled the `HttpCompressionMiddleware`?

Comment: brotli.error: BrotliDecompress failed
 brotli didn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`"Accept-Encoding": "text/html;charset=utf-8"` looks wrong. Try `"Accept-Encoding": "gzip"`, or removing it altogether.

Comment: Thank you so much, i am 99% i tried this but it ended up working thank you. Also may have been setting COOKIE_ENABLED to true